# Wordpress Rest API route is showing 404 error at localhost

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I have create a theme in WordPress 4.8. When i trying to connect Rest API is showing me 404 error at my local but on my domain it is working fine.

I have navigated to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and opened `000-default`

All of the `AllowOverride` variables were set to `None`, which I replaced with `All`.

But still it is not working at my localhost.

Comment: Please read [ask], show us some code and address which is returning errors.

Comment: refer below URL. its explained better,
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270309/create-a-new-post-from-hybrid-mobile-app-in-wordpress-using-json-api-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a host name in localhost and try to access the API through host name

For change host name goto /etc directory

And open hosts file in text editor and add below line

domain.com 127.0.0.1

And save it, then restart the apache service

It is working for me, hope this will help you.

Comment: It is working for me, but I need to replace localhost url to new host URL in DB
Thank! Its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions and try to use chmod -R 777 for Your WordPress folder

Comment: I have changed the permission, but still, it is showing **404 error**

Comment: What error do You see in Chrome console ? I'm always use nginx not apache but maybe this is something like wrong path to public directory with index.html, index.php ?

Comment: It is showing me "The requested URL /neweconomist/wp-json/wp/v2/posts was not found on this server" in response and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in the console.

Comment: And when You change permalinks to "Plain" in admin ? Or You do not have access to admin also ? Really hard to say, You got something wrong with apache config.

Comment: I have reinstall the apache2 and also change the permalink but still issue not resolve.

Please someone help me.